# XML structure for queries

Tags: xml, structure, dynamic-queries

I am going to create a XML structure for any query, and I want to use it with Model class which describe that xml structure itself. I have such kind of queries: [ split col: column1 on: ',' limit: 2 quote: '\"']

```
 <Functions>
<Groups>
  <Function name="Load">
    <Group name="Load">
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter type="CSV" source="${}"/>
        <Parameter type="CSV" source="${}" statements="limit" value="10">

        </Parameter>
      </Parameters>
    </Group>
    <Group>
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter name="SQL" type="SQL" source="${}"/>

      </Parameters>
    </Group>
  </Function>

</Groups>
```

But, there's just hard code. How can I do these statements dynamic  such as limit,offset, in this structure ? Can someone help ?